# Sketching sets defined on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to draft the set $|z−1|=|1-z^*|$ in the complex plane.
 $z^*$ is conjugate.
So,
$|x+iy-1|=|-x+iy+1|$,
$x^2-2x+1+y^2=x^2-2x+1+y^2$ and they eliminate each other.
Can't get my head around it, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Well, for which values of $z$ is the equation true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *every* complex number $z$, you have $\lvert z-1\rvert=\left\lvert\overline z-1\right\rvert$, because, if $z=x+yi$, with $x,y\in\mathbb R$, both of those numbers are equal to $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}$. So, your set is simply $\mathbb C$ itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i get it!